# Direct login link pros and cons

Tags: security, authentication

Sometimes on sites you see a link where you can login directly (without needing to fill in a form), for example like so:

www.domain.com/account/343654-SDFh454-45

Clicking that link directs me directly to MY account.

I was wondering, is this a good practice?

I mean, the pros and cons I can come up with:

pro:
- easy for user to login quickly

con:
- link may be in browser history so other users may access it

Anything else?

Comment: Those links probably expire after one use, so this is not much of an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to note:

1. Normally, if your credentials aren't saved, even having that link requires a username and password.
2. It is good practice.
3. If you were to give us a specific example on a site, it would be easier to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

A persistent cookie may be more suitable, depending on what you require.

If you want users, wherever they are and on any machine, to be able to log into with typing in their username and password then your direct login link trumps persistent cookies. But bear in mind that that means *anyone* can log in from anywhere, on any machine (if they know the link).

Weigh up how sensitive is the information is in the site against how convenient you want to make it for users.

You could email the user every time the link is user (and contain a link to immediately log off all their sessions) so that if the "magic" link was compromised the exposure could be reduced.

Also consider making it a user option, let them decide how sensitive their information is.